# VueJS & Laravel Multipage

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, multipage

Is it possible to have a laravel app that basically uses Vue instead of jQuery? I do not want a SPA, I just want to be able to make requests and manipulate DOM via Vue instead of jQuery. How should I do this? Any advices? I know about Livewire / Inertia, I just want to build something myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use vue and use vue component where you want to hook js or have ajax request. You can use vue component directly in the blade file.

You can check how to you in this youtube video / channel.
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxOV7EjF-Oc)